# Excel: Is it possible to Lookup multiple values in a different sheet and use the Sum function to add them together?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need help with a look up/sum function

I have 2 sheets in one workbook.
In Sheet One, in Column A, I have various names, and in Column B, I have numbers. Some names are repeated.
Eg:

[image: Sheet 1 Example]

In Sheet Two, in Column A, I have those names listed again, alphabetically, with duplicates removed. In Column B, i want to put a function that sees the name in Column A, and then goes through Sheet One and adds up all the values relating to that name.
EG:
Colin is in Sheet 2, Column A. In Sheet 2, Column B, the formula should return 3, as the sum of all values next to Colin in Sheet One is 3 (2,1).
Tanya would return only 1 as this name is only mentioned once in Sheet One.
So it should look like this:

[image: How it should look]

I hope this is clear.

I have tried:

> =SUM(VLOOKUP(A1,'Sheet One'!A:B,2,FALSE))

But that is only returning the first value it finds.
So for Colin it will only return "1".
How do I tell it to find all the values, add them all together and then return a number?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SUMIF` function:

```
=SUMIF(F6:F23,A6,G6:G23)
```

The first range will be the column with the multiple duplicate name rows.
The second parameter is the cell that houses the unique name value.
The third range is the column that contains the sum values.

You would use something similar to

```
=SUMIF('Sheet One'!A1:A20,A1,'Sheet One'!B1:B20)
```

Comment: I have edited my answer